# Trying to hover over a sentence and have that sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple event where, when the user hovers over a unique sentence in a box of sentences, the prefixed image div on the left slides left (like image goes out and another one slides in) to show the current sentences image. When not hovering over anything, the home image shows as default image. Also, the sentences aren't structured to be on new lines, some of them go on to a new line (cannot change this).

I can't post a picture, but I tried to explain it as detailed as possible.

How should I structure this? Should I use span tags inside of a div to identify the unique sentences so that I can set that span's background color and image event when hover over?

Please let me know the best possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: Wrapping your sentences in `<span>` tags seems like a good idea. Make it easier by giving those `<span>` tags a class to identify them. You could use `data-attributes` to store which image should be displayed, like: `<span class="foobar" data-foo="bar">This is a very special sentence.</span>`

Comment: I already wrapped each sentence in unique spans, but I don't know how to format the pictures that go along with the spans. I was thinking I could place all the images in a div and hide each one besides the default, then have the mouseover event work its magic?

Comment: Could you post some code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: sure i'll post it when i'm out of work at 5:30, thanks

Comment: @PaulD.Waite here is it on jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ws9h8/1/

the images obviously aren't visible, but you can see that they are moving around from the jQuery.

Comment: any other suggestions on the jQuery side for more precise code? I'll be trying to fix it in the meantime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first inclination is that yes, you will need to wrap your particular pieces of text in `<span>`'s in order to make them hoverable (to the exclusion of the text around them). Semantically it also makes the most sense. You will then have to give the span some kind of id that you can use to tie in with the desired effect.

Roughly, your markup would look like this:

```
<p>This is your before your sample sentence. <span id="hover_1">This IS your sample sentence.</span> <span id="hover_2">This is yet another sample sentence.</span> This is after your sample sentence.</p>
<div id="images">
  <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7171/6717705777_268acd6b2a_m.jpg" id="original" />
  <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7014/6717705405_80e172b437_m.jpg" id="hover_1_pic" /> 
  <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7144/6717706163_68e9b6f0d4_m.jpg" id="hover_2_pic" /> 
</div>
```

Now you'll need some css:

```
span { background: yellow; cursor: pointer;}
#images img { display: none; }
#images #original { display: block; }
```

Then your jQuery could look something like this:

```
$('span').hover( 
function(){
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#images img').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    $('#' + thisId + '_pic').delay(300).fadeIn('normal');
},
function(){
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + thisId + '_pic').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast',function(){
    $('#original').stop(true, true).fadeIn('normal');
    });
    $('#original').stop(true, true).css('opacity', 1); 
}
);
```

I don't know how many of these sentences you plan to have in this page, or how many pages, so you may have to work on making the jQuery selector a little smarter.

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/mMw5x/

Comment: Hey Dan thanks for the quick response, and yes, it is all on one page. There are a total of 9 sentences that are inside of a div, and to the left of this paragraph div is an image div to hold the images possibly based on the each sentence.

Comment: Dan - thanks for the fix.

Ben - if it's just one page, and you don't use spans anywhere else, just make the jQuery selector $('span').hover...

Comment: I agree chip, but I don't really know the process of how to relate specific span elements to their images.

Comment: I've edited the orignal post - as long as the span id is "foo" and the image id is "foo_pic", the above logic would work.

Comment: Ben - I've made one more edit - note the selector with thisId - I had forgotten the "#".

Comment: I tried testing the above locally, but I couldn't get the image to change via jQuery events. I added css for when hovering over a span, change the background and font color, which works. Any ideas?

Comment: Ben - I've gone back and fleshed the function out. I made it handle multiple images better, and added some animation cleanup. The core logic is still the same, so I don't know what you were unable to get working. If you want to see this in action, check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/mMw5x/

Comment: I checked yours out on fiddle, and I must say, it has a nice transition! But I'm having the same problem as before: when i hover over a span, the image doesn't change :-/

I found this in the console in chrome: "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined."
- I know that this resource errors means that i have a type="text/normal" or something somewhere, but could this be why the  image's aren't changing?

Comment: That error shouldn't prevent this from working. Can you post your code somewhere? Or, at the very least, put what you're doing in a fiddle?

Comment: I put it up on jsfiddle, and changed the original image and 2 others so I could see them, but only the original was showing at all times.

http://jsfiddle.net/RRD82/

Comment: As far as the fiddle goes, the issue in it was that jQuery wasn't enabled. On the left, under "choose framework" make sure jQuery is selected then run it again. I guess I would make sure the jQuery library is loading in your development environment.